# Clone a hard drive Windows 7 / Windows Server

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, clone, small-business-server

Quick question, i have purchased a hard drive cloning bay, where you put your hard drive with data / os in and a blank one and it supposedly clones it, now i haven't done this yet, what i was wondering is has anyone had any experience with this, does it make an exact clone with OS and all settings, for example, if i take the hard drive (lets call it HD1) from a computer (CP1) and make a clone of the hard drive then put the clone into (CP1) will it carry on as normal, so the computer is the same, the hard drive has just been cloned and swapped from the original drive to the cloned one, will this work for windows small business server also ?

Comment: Your assumption should be correct. You should read the the manual provided by the manufacturer of the cloning bay if you want 100% certainty. Just make sure to put the source drive and destination drive into the correct slot!

Comment: Sounds good, so essentially so long as i use the docking system correctly, then in theory all should be correct....thanks MonkeyZeus, i will keep post open for 24 hours in case someone else replies with a differing opinion, should nobody post, ill accept your answer on here, thanks again.

Comment: Remember that Hardware should match when cloning (in case one image for many devices), at least chip-set, CPU or other critical hw. if there are many differences you can get a blue screen

Comment: As said in the original post - "if i take the hard drive (lets call it HD1) from a computer (CP1) and make a clone of the hard drive then put the clone into (CP1) will it carry on as normal, so the computer is the same, the hard drive has just been cloned and swapped from the original drive to the cloned one" So the computer is identical.

Comment: ok if you use as a backup will be no problems. The only problem (rarely) will be the software licence. Some soft licence calculate the serial key of program activation to your hw serials including hdd S/N but anyway this is an old very strict technic that now is no longer applied

Comment: @emirjonb it is worth noting that [Sysprep](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721940%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) can be used if you are moving a Windows install from one PC to a different one with different hardware.

Comment: @ashjones86: Actually MonkeyZeus hasn't posted an actual answer, so you cannot accept it till he does so.